# Why do some variables being uninitialized cause an error, while others cause a warning?

Tags: ruby, language-design

The blog post [Uninitialized variables](http://sergeyenin.com/uninitialized-variables) points out that uninitialized class variables, local variables and constants cause an exception (after going through `method_missing` or their equivalent), while uninitialized global variables and instance variables only cause a warning.

Is there a logic to which ones cause an exception, and which cause only a warning?

Comment: As a side note, the verbose mode (the one triggered by `-w` switch) is somewhat [broken](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2011/06/ruby-verbose-mode/); If we ignore global variables as an unnecessary evil, I'd rather read your question as "why does access to uninitialized class, local variables and constants cause an exception, and access to uninitialized instance variables is perfectly valid?"

Comment: @whitequark: I'd recommend anyone reading that blog post to also read [this blog post](http://avdi.org/devblog/2011/06/23/how-ruby-helps-you-fix-your-broken-code/).

Comment: I had no doubt someone will raise that point. Personally, I think that convenience of, for example, shorthand memoization exceeds the actual impact of this class of errors. Just run your tests... Don't have any? OK. My IDE highlights identifiers that are only used once in entire project.

Comment: @whitequark: What IDE do you use?

Comment: [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/). It has regular spell checking too, but as I'm Russian and working on some local project where *most* of the identifiers are misspelled... I just turned it off.

Comment: ahem. Ruby does not warn on `||=` for [quite a long time](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/doc/ChangeLog-1.8.0#13593); well, there are still a lot of valid cases where instance variables should default to `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that exceptions are provided when they might be useful in metaprogramming.  You can easily instantiate a global variable or instance variable if you find it is missing -- I see the idiom often:

```
@var ||= 'default_value'
```

No need for anything fancy.

For classes, other constants and methods, it's more awkward to check if they are defined and use them inline.  The exceptions (and the associated methods like `const_missing` and `method_missing` provide hooks to handle their absence.  For example, I believe Rails uses `const_missing` to load classes at run time.

Comment: As I have noted, the `||=` construct [does not](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/doc/ChangeLog-1.8.0#13593) cause a warning.